# Searching in graphs trees with Depth/Breadth first/A* algorithms

Tags: language-agnostic, search, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I have a couple of questions about searching in graphs/trees:

Let's assume I have an empty chess board and I want to move a pawn around from point A to B.

A. When using depth first search or breadth first search must we use open and closed lists ? This is, a list that has all the elements to check, and other with all other elements that were already checked? Is it even possible to do it without having those lists? What about A*, does it need it?

B. When using lists, after having found a solution, how can you get the sequence of states from A to B? I assume when you have items in the open and closed list, instead of just having the (x, y) states, you have an "extended state" formed with (x, y, parent_of_this_node) ?

C. State A has 4 possible moves (right, left, up, down). If I do as first move left, should I let it in the next state come back to the original state? This, is, do the "right" move? If not, must I transverse the search tree every time to check which states I've been to?

D. When I see a state in the tree where I've already been, should I just ignore it, as I know it's a dead end? I guess to do this I'd have to always keep the list of visited states, right?

E. Is there any difference between search trees and graphs? Are they just different ways to look at the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A. When using depth first search or
>   breadth first search must we use open
>   and closed lists ?

With DFS you definitely need to store at least the current path. Otherwise you would not be able to backtrack. If you decide upon maintaining a list of all visited (closed) nodes, you are able to detect and avoid cycles (expanding the same node more than once). On the other side you don't have the space efficiency of DFS anymore. DFS without closed list only needs space proportional to the depth of the search space.

With BFS you need to maintain an open list (sometimes called fringe). Otherwise the algorithm simply can't work. When you additionally maintain a closed list, you will (again) be able to detect/avoid cycles. With BFS the additional space for the closed list might be not that bad, since you have to maintain the fringe anyway. The relation between fringe size and closed list size strongly depends upon the structure of the search space, so this has to be considered here. E.g. for a branching factor of 2, both lists are equal in size and the impact of having the closed list doesn't seem very bad compared to its benefits.

> What about A*, does it need it?

A*, as it can be seen as some special (informed) type of BFS, needs the open list. Omitting the closed list is more delicate than with BFS; also deciding upon updating costs inside the closed list. Depending upon those decisions, the algorithm can stop being optimal and/or complete depending on the type of heuristic used, etc. I won't go into details here.

> B.

Yup, the closed list should form some kind of inverse tree (pointers going towards the root node), so you can extract the solution path. You usually need the closed list for doing this. For DFS, your current stack is exactly the solution path (no need for closed list here). Also note that sometimes you are not interested in the path but only in the solution or the existence of it.

> C.

Read previous answers and look for the parts which talk about the detection of cycles.

> D.

To avoid cycles with a closed list: don't expand nodes that are already inside the closed list. Note: with path-costs coming into play (remember A*), things might get more tricky.

> E. Is there any difference between
>   search trees and graphs?

You could consider searches that maintain a closed list to avoid cycles as graph-searches and those without one tree-searches.

Answer (score 2):

A) It's possible to avoid the open/closed lists - you could try all possible paths, but that would take a VERY long time.

B) Once you've reached the goal, you use the parent_of_this_node information to "walk backwards" from the goal. Start with the goal, get its parent, get the parent's parent, etc. until you reach the start.

C) I think it doesn't matter - there's no way that the step you describe would result in a shorter path (unless your steps have negative weight, in which case you can't use Dijkstra/A*). In my A* code, I check for this case and ignore it, but do whatever is easiest to code up.

D) It depends - I believe Dijkstra can never reopen the same node (can someone correct me on that?). A* definitely can revisit a node - if you find a shorter path to the same node, you keep that path, otherwise you ignore it.

E) Not sure, I've never done anything specifically for trees myself.

There's a good introduction to A* here:
http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/
that covers a lot of details about how to implement the open set, pick a heuristic, etc.

Comment: My point in C is that if are using just depth first or breadth first (not A*), if I am not mistaken, you get infinite sequences of paths.

Comment: OK, a little more thought on C: in non-A*, the previous point should be marked as closed, so you'd never revisit it. In A*, as mentioned, it is possible to re-open nodes, so you have to consider opening it.

Answer (score 1):

A. Open and Closed lists are common implementation details, not part of the algorithm as such. It's common to do a depth-first tree search without either of these for example, the canonical way being a recursive traversal of the tree.

B. It is typical to ensure that nodes refer back to previous nodes allowing for a plan to be reconstructed by following the back-links. Alternatively you just store the entire solution so far in each candidate, though it would then be misleading to call it a node really.

C. I'm assuming that moving left and then moving right bring you to an equivalent state - in this case, you would have already explored the original state, it would be on the closed list, and therefore should not have been put back onto the open list. You don't traverse the search tree each time because you keep a closed list - often implemented as an O(1) structure - for precisely this purpose of knowing which states have already been fully examined. Note that you cannot always assume that being in the same position is the same as being in the same state - for most game path-finding purposes, it is, but for general purpose search, it is not.

D. Yes, the list of visited states is what you're calling the closed list. You also want to check the open list to ensure you're not planning to examine a given state twice. You don't need to search any tree as such, since you typically store these things in linear structures. The algorithm as a whole is searching a tree (or a graph), and it generates a tree (of nodes representing the state space) but you don't explicitly search through a tree structure at any point within the algorithm.

E. A tree is a type of graph with no cycles/loops in it. Therefore you use the same graph search procedure to search either. It's common to generate a tree structure that represents your search through the graph, which is represented implicitly by the backwards links from each node to the node that preceded/generated it in the search. (Although if you go down the route of holding the entire plan in each state, there will be no tree, just a list of partial solutions.)